# Is there an ability to position clip-path from right edge?

Tags: css, clip-path

I have a hamburger icon positioned 2rem from the right and top edges, and I'd like a clip path to grow from the centre point behind it, which is easy to calculate, but with the `clip-path: circle(10px at center);` syntax, I haven't been able to find anything along the lines of `right 2rem top 2rem`.

Is this even possible or do I need to use an SVG mask instead?

Comment: please share example code

Comment: @Ranjithv there is already the needed code and detail inside the question

Comment: @Temani Afif  i think you got solution right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider percentage value:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  clip-path: circle(50px at 100% 50%); /* left 100% (right) top 50% (center)*/
  
  /* 0    0    = left top
     0    100% = left bottom
     100% 0    = right top
     100% 100% = right bottom
     ... and so on
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Then you can consider `calc()` for the offeset

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  clip-path: circle(50px at calc(100% - 2rem) 50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't even think to test calc(). This works great, cheers. Working styles: `circle(2rem at calc(100% - 3rem) 3rem)`